# Is $(-1)^t A$ a stationary process?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, time-series

> If $A$ is a random variable with $E(A)=0$ and $Var(A)=1$, is $(-1)^t
>  A$ a stationary process?

Well if $t$ is even $Z_t=A$ and if $t$ is odd $Z_t=-A$, so the process change with time. Is it enough to show that a process is not stationary or I need to show that one of the conditions of a stationary process not hold?

Comment: Sorry but when are you going to start to apply the definition of stationarity of a random process to the ones you post about on the site, just to check if they are indeed stationary or not?

Comment: @Did I'm doing some exercises that ask to check if a process is stationary. Not sure if it is what you asking, I'm not a english native speaker.

Comment: @Roland Are you talking about wide-sense stationary process?

Comment: @MathLover Second-order stationarity

Comment: No, I am asking why you are posting a string of posts on quite close problems without any personal input, using in effect the site as a do-my-homework-for-me free service.

Answer (score 2):

If the distribution of $A$ is symmetric, that is, the same as the distribution of $-A$, then your process is stationary.  Otherwise not.

Comment: It's a good point, although the exercise does not mention anything about symmetry

Answer (score 1):

Let $X(t)=(-1)^t A$. If $t$ is an integer (or equivalently, $X(t)$ takes on real values), then $X(t)$ is a second-order stationary process.

First, $$\mathbb{E}[X(t)]=(-1)^t \mathbb{E}[A]=0.$$
Second, $$\mathbb{E}[X(t)X(t+\tau)]=\mathbb{E}[(-1)^{2t+\tau} A^2]=(-1)^{\tau}.$$

Therefore, the process is a second-order stationary process.